# issue with form_open codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-3

I have a strange issue with the `codeigniter` `form_open` function.

When I pass this code:

```
<?php echo form_open('login/check');?>
```

It actually prints out this

```
<form action="http://***.***.***.***/***/index.php/login" method="post" accept-charset="<meta charset="utf-8">">
```

The error is exactly at the end of the form open tag. Where is located the `accept-charset` attribute. Besides the fact that I do not need the `accept-charset` attribute, since I've declared the meta in the head, it's printing it in a wrong format!

```
accept-charset="<meta charset="utf-8">">
```

This code outputs on the page the form and the double quotes and the angular closing.

```
">
```

The real problem it's not the `accept-charset` attribute itself but the wrong printing of it. Instead of `accept-charset="utf-8"` it pulls in the meta tag of the charset

What's happening? I can't figure this out...
Thank you all!

Comment: @Kayathiri thanks for the edit ;)

Comment: Well, acc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html , form open always adds that attribute

Comment: @Uzumaki Ichigo Ok, and that's fine since in my other applications it adds the attribute and works fine. The question now is... why it is behaving like that? O.O

Comment: Have you configure your site : $config['base_url'] in config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the documentation of Codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html . It says that if you are using `form_open()` then it creates an opening form tag with a base URL built from your config preferences. It will optionally let you add form attributes and hidden input fields, and **will always add the attribute accept-charset based on the charset value in your config file**.

Also try this it should works as it will not override if already defined in the attributes.

```
$attributes = array(
     'accept-charset'=>'utf8'
);
echo form_open('login/check', $attributes);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! But my problem is not the accept-charset itself, but how it's being handled. Instead of typing accept-charset="utf-8" it types accept-charset"<meta charset="utf-8" ... and so on this generates the "> on my body due the wrong ending of the form... in ellislab forum it says that it should print only accept-charset="utf-8"...

Comment: What is the value in your config.php file for accept-charset? Is it like this $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

Comment: Hi! In my config i have only $config['charset'] specified and it seems ok..
this is the string: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

Comment: You said you have declared the meta in the head. Did you check after commenting the meta? may be it is overriding the meta declaration in form_open().

Comment: @AmitRay Ellislab not doing any thing with CI anymore use the links from here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: I've tried that before writing the post, but the error still remains. I've found the form_open function inside the system folder, obviously if I comment out  the part of the accept-charset the problem dissapears.  (line 88 of form_helper). But this doesn't seem the proper solution dough...

Comment: @wolfgang1983 that's true, but even on the codeigniter official pages there's the same reference about form_open as in ellislab...

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks. I just googled it and got the link.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! Always better than editing the core system file.
But doesn't seem strange this behavior? It's literally 'misspelling' the attribute... anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured base_url in config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project'; //your project location
```

and also load form helper in controller

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Base url is set, and the form is loaded inside the autoload file.

Comment: It is good to end your base url with / like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';`